# Comparing two dates in array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form where I am fetching two Dates from input tag. I need to validate and compare a date should always be greater than the another date. Here is javascript below :

```
function validateDD(gateout_plnd_dt){
    var dt_pat = /^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}$/;
    var alpha = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\.\-]+$/
    var int = /^[0-9.]+$/;
    var gateout_plnd_dt = document.getElementsByName('gateout_plnd_dt[]');
    var gate_in_dt = document.getElementsByName('gate_in_dt[]');


    for(var i=0,j=0; i<gateout_plnd_dt.length,j<gate_in_dt.length; i++,j++){



        if(gateout_plnd_dt[i].value< gate_in_dt[j].value){
        alert((gateout_plnd_dt[i].value));
        alert(gate_in_dt[j].value);
         return false;
        }
        }


    }
```

I need to convert it from string into date object which i am unable to do so. Will be really helpful to get it done. Thanks.

Comment: Check out moment js.. It has parser based on date format

Comment: will it work in array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
for(var i=0; i<gateout_plnd_dt.length; i++){

    out_date = gateout_plnd_dt[i].split("-");
    in_date = gate_in_dt[i].split("-");
    gateout_date = new Date(out_date[1],out_date[0],out_date[2]).getTime()
    gatein_date = new Date(in_date[1],in_date[0],in_date[2]).getTime()

    if(gateout_date < gatein_date ){
    alert(gateout_plnd_dt[i]);
    alert(gate_in_dt[i]);
     return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Change the split(-) to split("-");@Preethi Mano

Answer (score 1):

Try this i works for you.

```
var parts ='you string'.split("-");
var mydate = new Date(parts[2],parts[0],parts[1]);
```

Comment: I have edited it let me know. If that works for you.@user3445158

Comment: it works for single date input form, but not in array of input with multiple date. on checikng in Inspect element in console section, it show "'you string'.split("-"); is not a function"

Comment: what value you will have in this.     gateout_plnd_dt[i].value

Comment: As per my code i am entering multiple date though gateout_plnd_dt in mysql table.I already have a date value in gate_in_dt. So gateout_plnd_dt>gate_in_dt .

Comment: each element in the list is string right.@user3445158

Comment: Yes. when i do alert for as shown in code, it show me in MM-DD-YYYY

Comment: Answer is already posted by **Preethi Mano**. That works check it out.

Answer (score 0):

convert date to timestamp. I wouldn't suggest using a library for that reason.

```
 function datetotimestamp(date){
    var date=date.split("-");
    var newd=date[1]+"/"+date[0]+"/"+date[2];
    return new Date(newd).getTime();
    }
```

> console.log( datetotimestamp("26-02-2012") < datetotimestamp("25-02-2012"))  //returns false

to compare two or more values in array, use an extra function

```
var compareinarray = function(array) {
    for(var i = 1; i < array.length; i++)    {
        if(datetotimestamp(array[i]) > datetotimestamp(array[i-1]))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

var arr = ["26-02-2012", "23-02-2012"];
var res = compareinarray(arr); 
console.log(res)
```

update the compareinarray function var, according to your case and array complexity.

Comment: This will work for single date input, but fails in array